# Assign sequential ID from range based on cell text and previously used range value in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to populate a field with a sequentially unique number from a given range dependent on a string/product type.

There are three products (ProdA, ProdB, and ProdC) and when one of the three products is selected from a field, I want a number generated sequentially from a range of numbers where (ProdA=100-199, ProdB=200-299, and ProdC=300-399)

Product, Article#
ProdA, 101
ProdA, 102
ProdC, 301
ProdB, 201
ProdC, 302
ProdA, 103
ProdB, 202

I have used  =if(A2="ProdA",100,if(A2="ProdB",200,if(A2="ProdC",300))) and then manually changed the last digit to the next unused digit in the range.

I have also tried several iterations with Javascript for use in the script editor without success.

Any direction or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE: I am using the following ArrayFormula in Google Sheets:

`=ArrayFormula(if(len(A:A),{"Count";if(A2:A="ProdA",A2:A&", "&100+index(sort(iferror({sort(row(A2:A),A2:A,1),row(A2:A)-row()+1-vlookup(sort(A2:A),{unique(A2:A),iferror(match(unique(A2:A),sort(A2:A),0))},2,0)})),,2),)},))`

If "ProdA" is selected from drop-down in A2, it returns a unique and sequential value starting with 100, but includes the "Prod A" in the output. For example: "ProdA, 101". Preference is only to include number value from array (e.g. "101"). Almost there...

Answer (score 0):

The following ArrayFormula resolved my issue:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(H:H),{"Count";if(H2:H="ProdA",100+index(sort(iferror({sort(row(H2:H),H2:H,1),row(H2:H)-row()+1-vlookup(sort(H2:H),{unique(H2:H),iferror(match(unique(H2:H),sort(H2:H),0))},2,0)})),,2),if(H2:H="ProdB",200+index(sort(iferror({sort(row(H2:H),H2:H,1),row(H2:H)-row()+1-vlookup(sort(H2:H),{unique(H2:H),iferror(match(unique(H2:H),sort(H2:H),0))},2,0)})),,2),if(H2:H="ProdC",300+index(sort(iferror({sort(row(H2:H),H2:H,1),row(H2:H)-row()+1-vlookup(sort(H2:H),{unique(H2:H),iferror(match(unique(H2:H),sort(H2:H),0))},2,0)})),,2))))},))
```